# Low val_accuracy in first fold of k-fold cross validation at every try

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I have some problems at implementing kfold for sentiment analysis,I have used kfold with for-loop technique but ı get smallest accuracy first fold whenever run my code .After first fold val_accuracy always increase. There is a 10% gap between first fold val_accuracy and the other folds val_accuracy(like75-85), somebody in here advised me using built in cross_val_score instead of using for -loop , but cross_val_score havent got earlystop, callbacks etc.Every article about kfold cross validation says that, model training start from scratch for each fold, but ı have always increasing accuracy and the least one is first fold.

Here is related part

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True,random_state=7)
for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(skf.split(X, y.argmax(1))): X_train_skf, X_test_skf = X[train_index], X[test_index] y_train_skf, y_test_skf = y[train_index], y[test_index]

```
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(np.argmax(y_train_skf, 1)), np.argmax(y_train_skf, 1))
class_weights = {i : class_weights[i] for i in range(3)}
print(class_weights)

model.fit(np.array(X_train_skf), np.array(y_train_skf),
            epochs=2000,
            validation_data=(X_test_skf,y_test_skf),
            batch_size=256,
            verbose=1,
            class_weight=class_weights,
            callbacks = [es,lr_sched])

y_true, y_pred = np.argmax(y_test_skf, 1), np.argmax(model.predict(X_test_skf), 1)
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, digits=3))
      
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
scores.append(accuracy)
```

Comment: or do you have any idea to solve small accuracy at first fold?

Comment: Ther ara some questions in here but ı cant comment them because ı havent got eneough point, and no body answer my question,